# How to repeat code in java

Tags: java, swing

So for a school project I'm doing, I am copying the same code and pasting it, just changing the Identifier name.

```
if (s1.isSelected()){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    String query = "update booking set s1 = 0 where bdate ='"+d+"';";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }

if (s2.isSelected()){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    String query = "update booking set s2 = 0 where bdate ='"+d+"';";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
if (s3.isSelected()){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    String query = "update booking set s3 = 0 where bdate ='"+d+"';";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
```

How do I repeat this code for 100-120 times? Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: [You are WET. Get DRY.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) This seems to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: why you want to repeat your code 100-120 times?

Comment: Do you have 100-120 checkboxes.

Comment: @YCF_L I'm making a booking system. That is the code for the Book button. I have 100 seats so instead of changing the code manually I was wondering if there's automatic code generators which would save me a lot of time.

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- I have 100 toggle buttons, yep.

Comment: In this case I would like to store all the 100 toggle buttons in a list then loop over this list and check each one if it is selected change your query, in the end execute just one query

Comment: but, don't tell you have for each toggle buttons an attribute in the database? I think this is a bad design :(

Comment: Components can be created in loop. BTW very wide table design seems bad too.

Comment: Another question is that required to use toggle buttons there are many better components that can help you more

Comment: Map the `JCheckBox` or value to the query or identifier; make use `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Read about

```
void putClientProperty(Object key, Object value);
```

and

```
Object getClientProperty(Object key);
```

Almost every GUI system, binary Win32 too, has similar concept to store specific data with/in component. This drastically eliminate stupid repeatable code, strange `if`s series etc. For example

```
List<JCheckBox> boxes = ... ;

for(...){
    JCheckBox box = ... // create, add listeners and position component by code
    boxes.add(box);
    box.putClientProperty("seat", anSeatObject );
}
```

when required, in event listener, or during save phase this information can be read;

Additional note on the margin: personally I prefer table with SeatsByDate, not hundreds of column. In your model querying for free seats is almost impossible.
Because I prefer JPA, I will make entity

```
@Enitity 
SeatsByDate {
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne
  ReserationDate date;

  bool isReserved;
}
```

and then

```
 SeatsByDate  anSeatObject
```

So JPA is my personal preference, `ClientProperty` may be simple string too.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<JCheckBox> boxArray = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
boxArray.add(box1);
boxArray.add(box2);
//.....
for(int i = 0;i<boxArray.size();i++){
  JCheckBox box = boxArray.get(i);
  String indexStr = i + 1;
  if(box.isSelected()){
      System.out.println("Hello");
      String query = "update booking set s" + indexStr+"= 0 where bdate ='"+d+"'";
      stmt.executeUpdate(query);
   }
}
```

Comment: `tempStr = s + i;`  - where is `s` defined ?  Also `"update booking set tempStr  = 0 where bdate ='"+d+"';"`  -  `tempStr` is just a String. It should be `..." + tempStr +".. `

Answer (score -1):

Make use of loop statements and functions to achieve that. You could use FOR statement in a case where you know how many repetitions you need.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops

Assuming you have an array or collections with all the seats, you could make a function to update a specific seat passed as an argument and call it as many times you want within the FOR statement. It would be something like this:

```
public void updateBooking(Seat seat) {
    // You'd need to add here some stuff like db connection
    if (seat.isSelected()){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String query = "update booking set " + seat.getId() + " = 0 where bdate ='" + d + "';";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, May I ask why the negative vote? I think the best DRY solution here would be creating a method similar to the one I posted, obviously the query would need a revision, and call it multiple times per each seat in a loop, with a FOR or WHILE statement.